# Is it possible to have an exported function in a DLL return a static member of an exported class?

Tags: plugins, dll, window

I'm working on a plug-in protocol of sorts. The idea is that there's a base clase PCOperatorBase and that plugins would subclass this base class to provide specific functionality through a "process" virtual method that they override. The subclasses also should have a static struct member that hold typical plugin info: plug name, type and subtype. This info is used by another class (a PCOperatorManager) to know what types of plugins is dealing with. And I thought about having it be a static member so that there's no need to instantiate a plug to merely find out about the type of operator it is.

I have the following classes:

**PCOperatorBase.h** the superclass from which to derive all other plugs:

```
#ifdef PCOPERATORBASE_EXPORTS
#define PCOPERATORBASE_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define PCOPERATORBASE_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class PCOPERATORBASE_API PCOperatorBase
{
public:

    typedef struct OperatorInfo
    {
        wchar_t* name;
        wchar_t* type;
        wchar_t* subtype;
    } OperatorInfo;

    PCOperatorBase(void);
    virtual ~PCOperatorBase(void);
    virtual int process(int* inBuffer, int* outBuffer, int bufferSize);
};
```

And then, for instance, a subclass:
**BlackNWhite.h:** a RGB->black / white operator -- yes, these are going to be graphics plugs, and disregard the types for the in / out buffers.. they are merely placeholders at this point.

```
#ifdef BLACKNWHITE_EXPORTS
#define BLACKNWHITE_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define BLACKNWHITE_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

// This class is exported from the BlackNWhite.dll
class BLACKNWHITE_API CBlackNWhite : PCOperatorBase 
{
public:
    static PCOperatorBase::OperatorInfo* operatorInfo;

    CBlackNWhite(void);
    virtual ~CBlackNWhite(void);
    //virtual int process(int* inBuffer, int* outBuffer, int bufferSize);

};


BLACKNWHITE_API CBlackNWhite* getOperatorInstance();
BLACKNWHITE_API const PCOperatorBase::OperatorInfo* getOperatorInfo();
```

And here the implementation file:
**BlackNWhite.cpp:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "BlackNWhite.h"

BLACKNWHITE_API CBlackNWhite* getOperatorInstance()
{
    return new CBlackNWhite();
}

BLACKNWHITE_API const PCOperatorBase::OperatorInfo* getOperatorInfo()
{
    return CBlackNWhite::operatorInfo;
}


CBlackNWhite::CBlackNWhite()
{
}

CBlackNWhite::~CBlackNWhite()
{
}
```

Now, I've tried a few approaches but I can't get the DLL to compile, because of the static member.The linker throws:

```
\BlackNWhite.lib and object c:\Projects\BlackNWhite\Debug\BlackNWhite.exp
1>BlackNWhite.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct PCOperatorBase::OperatorInfo * CBlackNWhite::operatorInfo" (?operatorInfo@CBlackNWhite@@2PAUOperatorInfo@PCOperatorBase@@A)
1>c:\Projects\BlackNWhite\Debug\BlackNWhite.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I thought that since the struct is defined inside the base class and the base class is exporting, the struct would export too. But I guess I'm wrong?

**So how should I be doing it?**

**And regardless, is there a better approach to having the plugs' factory export their name,type and subtype without the need for instantiation than a static class member?** For example, a resource file? or even another extern "C" function could return this info.. But I just felt that since it's C++ it makes the most sense to encapsulate this data (which is about the class as a factory itself) within the class, whether through a member or a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't have anything to do with DLLs, you declared the static member but you forgot to *define* it.  Add this line to BlackNWhite.cpp:

```
PCOperatorBase::OperatorInfo* CBlackNWhite::operatorInfo = NULL;
```

Comment: That works. But isn't that re-declaration of the member, meaning type id = rval (declaration + initialization)? The way I was thinking of it, the declaration was done in the interface (static whatever ... in the .h). I didn't remember needing to restate the type in the implementation...

Comment: And besides this specific case... how would I go about "forcing" subclasses to implement a static member of this struct for every subclass? Meaning, I want to establish some sort of interface (protocol if you will.. Objective-C mentality) that the subclasses need to implement. I thought about having the static member in the base class, but that doesn't make sense cause ALL subclasses will share the same operatorInfo. I need each subclass to be forced to implement a unique one